# Doubt about a normal vector to calculate flux of a vector field

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, surfaces, vector-fields

I want to calculate a flux of a vector field $\vec F(x,y,z)=(2xy,y,x^2)$ through the surface $S$ that is the piece of the plane $z+x=4$ inside the cylinder $x^2+y^2=4x$.
I used cylindrical coordinates to parameterize the surface. Then $x \to r\cos(\theta)+2$ and $y \to r\sin(\theta)$. So I'd parameterize the surface as

$$ \vec{r}(r,\theta) = \left< r\cos(\theta)+2, r\sin(\theta), 2 - r\cos(\theta) \right> $$

This way the bounds on the integral will be $0 \leq r \leq 2$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$.

The normal vector $\vec{N}$ is
$$
\vec{N} = \vec{r}_{r} \times \vec{r}_{\theta} = 
\left|
\begin{pmatrix}
\widehat{i} & \widehat{j} & \widehat{k} \\
\cos \theta & \sin \theta & -\cos \theta \\
-r \sin \theta & r \cos \theta & r \sin \theta \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\right| 
= \langle r, 0,r\rangle,  
$$

Here I want to graph this surface and also I need to know how to  indicate this normal vector on the graph.

I would also like to know if what I did so far is correct.

Comment: The work is correct.  However,  I would work as far as I could in Cartesian space before transforming the coordinate system, instead.

Comment: So my parameterization isn't correct?

Comment: No, it is correct.  It just isn't the easiest way to attack the problem.

Comment: oh I understand, parameterizing the plane would be easier. Thanks!